# How Do I Rank the GPA of Students from Different Colleges?

Tags: normalization, ranking

I have data from 100 students, each at a different college would like to rank them by GPA.  I have the following data for each:

1. The student's GPA: example 3.25
2. The all student average: 3.10
3. The highest possible GPA on that students campus, this is usually 4.0 but in some cases, MIT for example, the GPA is on a 5.0 scale.
4. The lowest possible GPA, in all cases 0.

The problem is that there is a wide range of all student GPA averages on the campuses, for example ranging from 2.5 to 3.5.  Half of the student are above their all campus GPA and half are below.

I do not want to take any other factors into considerations, such as Northwestern University in Chicago being a "better" school than "Northwestern Podunk University. We can make the assumption that on any campus there is a normal distribution of GPA.

Comment: If you don't want to take external information into consideration just $z$-transform them. It is a bit heavy-handed but in the absence of using any other ranking information is  "OKish". (Yes, the resulting distribution will be truncated which is suboptimal.)

Comment: I would use a random forest for this.   I would treat the GPA as input, but I would want a measure of "success" because folks are arguing they will be successful because of the GPA - that is (imo) its only purpose.    What does "success" mean in this case?

Comment: Another option would be to use ipsative rescaling and divide each student's GPA by the maximum possible value for that college. This would create a new metric ranging between 0 and 100 that would avoid the truncation issue of z-transforms.

Answer (score 1):

I would rescale MIT's subset so that the max GPA is also 4.0

Then you might want to construct a one-factor random effects ANOVA to check for variations in grading standards from school to school. If none of the estimate random effects are significant, you're probably good to proceed with just ranking all students together. However, if school-based effects do appear to be significant, you might have to do something more complicated like penalize GPA's of students from schools that have "naturally higher" GPA's (i.e. those that might be more prone to grade inflation).

That is still a bit of an oversimplified process, but hopefully it gives you something to start with.